# Customize SOAP header in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapheader

I am pretty new to SOAP and I would like to learn how to customize SOAP header. More specifically, I am trying to configure my outbound message SOAP header to be compliant with the expected format. The header is going to be used for authentication purposes.

This is what I have so far.

I have set up a method to add the security deader where I am trying to format the header as per specification.

```
private void addSecurityHeader(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) throws SOAPException {

public static final String WSSE_NS = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
public static final String WSSE_SECURITY_NAME = "Security";
public static final String WSSE_NS_PREFIX = "wsse";
public static final String SOAPENV_NS_PREFIX = "soapenv";

SOAPEnvelope envelope = messageContext.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader header = messageContext.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader();
SOAPBody body = messageContext.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();

// changing prefix to soapenv
envelope.setPrefix(SOAPENV_NS_PREFIX);
header.setPrefix(SOAPENV_NS_PREFIX);
body.setPrefix(SOAPENV_NS_PREFIX);

// adding security Element
Name securityName = soapFactory.createName(WSSE_SECURITY_NAME, WSSE_NS_PREFIX, WSSE_NS);
SOAPHeaderElement securityElement = header.addHeaderElement(securityName);
```

When I print out the message in Eclipse console, the Security element is in the following format:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
```

But this is the desired format of the Security format:

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
```

To summarize the issues that I need to address:

1) I need to change the SOAP-ENV to soapenv.

> SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1"

should be

> soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"

2) I need to remove

> xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

as it's not needed in this element.

Any tips how to accomplish it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: oh dear, what kind of badly-written server cares about the particular namespace prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I recently solved the issue in following way:-

1. Created SOAP Message from a template XML file

   ```
   BufferedReader rd  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("D:\\TestGetOppuService.xml")));
       StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer();
       String line = null;
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
       {
           if(line.indexOf("Current_TimeStamp")>0)
           {
               line = line.replaceAll("Current_TimeStamp", createTime);
           }
           if(line.indexOf("Expire_TimeStamp")>0)
           {
               line = line.replaceAll("Expire_TimeStamp", expiresTime);
           }
           if(line.indexOf("NONCE_STRING")>0)
           {
               line = line.replaceAll("NONCE_STRING", getNonceString(createTime));
           }
           fileContent.append(line + '\n');
       }
   ```
2. Be careful in sending TimeStamp. Client and Server clocks should be in Sync so be careful about the client and server machine's timezone
3. Nonce String should be encoded properly. I took help from:- 
    [Java Webservice Client UsernameToken equivalent to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806586/java-webservice-client-usernametoken-equivalent-to-php)
4. Here's how template XML file looks like:-

   ```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/sales/opptyMgmt/opportunities/opportunityService/types/">
   <soapenv:Header>
     <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-fasfwffsafsaf-asffsaf">
           <wsu:Created>Current_TimeStamp</wsu:Created>
           <wsu:Expires>Expire_TimeStamp</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-asfsafsaf-78787080affaf-saf">
           <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
           <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:Password>
           <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">NONCE_STRING</wsse:Nonce>
           <wsu:Created>Current_TimeStamp</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
     </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
     -----------Content------------
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
   ```